# XSS attack via this filter?

Tags: php, security, xss

```
function filter($p){
    $i=0;
    return str_replace("<","&lt;",str_replace(">","&gt;",str_replace("&","&amp;",$p,$i),$i),$i);
}
```

Any idea pass this xss prevention ? *just my idea , not homework*

Comment: Why don't you just use htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: suppose coder is noob and he doesnt know htmlspecialchar() :D
I dont talk about how to prevent , i wanna know how to attack :D

Comment: Offtopic - this site is not for reviewing code. That's what http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for.  But as a general rule, don't roll your own "security" code. Unless you're an expert, there'll ALWAYS be one or more edges cases that your code will let leak through.

Comment: `suppose coder is noob`.. if he don't know `htmlspecialchar()`, do you think he will remember your big filter option?

Comment: You called coder nob but uses several `str_replace` instead of an array of `$search` and `$replace` (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: @GabrielSantos: he was referring to himself as a beginner ;)

Comment: @phpdev, sorry for my miss understand. I'm  from Brazil =P

Comment: phpdev : i just suppose coder have some mistake ;) . dont be so hard with me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As raised in the question errata, the problem here is you're trying to roll your own replacement for [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in PHP. While you've asked for a spot code review for fixing a potential [XSS exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), you've actually indicated a design smell in your application regarding how you handle vulnerabilities.

While you can perform iterative fixups or input mode sanitization as you appear to be trying to do (note [this answer about black- and white-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9968832/517815)), you would be better served by reading [this documentation on how to address and mitigate XSS exploits](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/products_applied_mitigation_bulletin09186a008073f7b3.html) and [this additional documentation](http://www.infosecwriters.com/hhworld/hh8/csstut.htm). It should offer guidance on reviewing and rearchitecting your application to handle these threats cleanly and safely, instead of swiss-cheesing your mitigation strategy over multiple fixups in the code.

([Additional helpful resource](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html))

Best of luck with your application!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.  For instance, if `filter` is used *within* a HTML tag, like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=filter($p)?>">
```

The attacker might execute an XSS attack by coercing `$p` into being something like:

```
something" onfocus="javascript:alert('test')
```

So the output HTML becomes:

```
<input type="text" value="something" onfocus="javascript:alert('test')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use blacklist. Always use whitelist. [Read for example here](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) about plenty of different attacks. Thought-provoking :)